# Is List.where identical to List.filter?

Tags: f#

I intended to use `List.filter` but accidentally wrote `List.where` without noticing (I'm used to LINQ). To my surprise this function seems to actually exist and do the exact same thing as `List.filter`. However, I couldn't find any documentation on `List.where` on MSDN.

Are the two functions equivalent?

Comment: You should be able to see the documentation in the autocomplete and hover tips in your IDE. Unfortunately there is a bug in VS2017 where these are not shown for F# core functions.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug so I can follow it?

Comment: Actually, that's only for non-project files like an FSX. [See here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2926)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [they're identical](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1de369ca6f4564044ff6adee667a5da54f8b7138/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L426); I assume `.where`'s existence is solely for LINQ users who would wonder where it is otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful to have this officially confirmed - do you have a link to some documentation or relevant F# source?

Comment: @cmeeren - https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1de369ca6f4564044ff6adee667a5da54f8b7138/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L426

Comment: @cmeeren : I'm not aware of any current documentation; I'd love to find it as well. It's worth noting that the in-source documentation is the same for both though: [`.filter`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1de369ca6f4564044ff6adee667a5da54f8b7138/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fsi#L243-L249), [`.where`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1de369ca6f4564044ff6adee667a5da54f8b7138/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fsi#L868-L874)

Comment: I actually like "where" better, because "filter" always leaves me wondering "filter in, or filter out?" which I then solve by translating to "where" in my head anyway.